# Where does HOST_OPERATING_SYSTEM in uname.c comes from?

Tags: environment-variables, c

While reading [uname.c](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/uname.c) (in order to recreate it) I found a variable called `HOST_OPERATING_SYSTEM` (line 371). It's never mentioned in the same file (as Strg+f told me) and not in the dependencies of `uname.c`, as far as I could see.

Where is the variable initialized and how to access it?

Comment: I think this might get defined by the build system of the project (with some autoconf/automake macros?)

Comment: Check the Makefile, to see if some option to the compiler like `-DHOST_OPERATING_SYSTEM=something`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HOST_OPERATING_SYSTEM` is defined at build time using autoconf modules defined in [gnulib](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/m4/host-os.m4).

Comment: where is it stored? How does uname access it later on?

Comment: It's a C `#define`. It ends up hardcoded into the `uname` binary.